# soft body pinning

Tags: cloth-simulation, soft-body

Is it somehow possible to pin vertices in soft body simulation as it is possible to do it in cloth simulation? I have an object that I applied soft body simulation to, however, the settings cause it to fall down from the scene. I tried to use cloth with pinning, but the cloth seems to be too "soft" even if I applied "mega hard rubber" settings to it.

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

To pin vertices in a soft body simulation, just use the "Soft Body Goal" settings. You can specify a vertex group for the vertices you want to pin.

If you want it to behave like cloth, I think you want to set the default goal strength down to zero. Then, the soft body will hang down like cloth would.

Here is a test I did. I have the pinned vertices hooked to an empty:

[image: Pinned soft body screenshot]

Comment: Sorry for my limited knowledge, but how did you manage to pin those pnned verts to empty? Did you use hook modifier? Could you please post the blend file? Thx a lot

Comment: Yeah, just use a hook modifier and set the vertex group to the "pinned" group. Make sure the modifier is before the cloth modifier. I didn't keep the blend file though...